# Issue while adding multiple hosting nameservers

Tags: java, reactjs, amazon-web-services, hosting, netlify

I have purchased my domain from godaddy and now I'm trying to connect my domain to the backend using aws server and frontend using netlify hosting, for aws server I have used route53 and created subdomain: api.mydomain.com and added the nameservers to godaddy DNS configs and similarly at netlify end I have created subdomain: test.mydomain.com and added its nameserver also to godaddy but in this process only one subdomain is working either api. or test.

I'm new in this, and I can't figure it out where I'm doing worng.

Comment: We need some more information.  Can you share the domain name?  Name servers are specified in DNS and, while you can have multiple vendors, there is likely no need.  The key will be your SOA record.  That can be found via something like `dig -t SOA domain.tld`.  I don't think this question really has anything to do with java or reactjs though.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have things set up would only work some of the time. The Netlify servers have some records and Route53 has some records. If a DNS request for api. goes to a nameserver that doesn't have a record for api. an error will be returned. Until you reach a large enough scale, I'd recommend picking one service, putting all your records in that service, and entering those nameserver addresses into GoDaddy.

You can use multiple DNS providers but only if records for all hosts exist in each one (the endpoints for those records could be different) but api. and www. would need to exist on all providers in your case.